# Working with jQuery independent selectors with classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I'm trying to work with a `jQuery` `plug-in` which can work with a `list` of jquery object passed by invoking the plug-in.

The plugin works perfect If I pass a list of children, but I get problems if the selectors are once per parent, here is the example:

```
// this works, every element is treated independently
<script>
$('.image').plugInName ();
</script>
<div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

the problem is here:

```
// this won't work, every element is treated as the first one
<script>
$('.image').plugInName ();
</script>
<div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Inside the plug-in I've used a for loop to make the objects independent.
I know I can use an `id`, I was just wonder if there was some alternative solution

http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/CFPTa/

Comment: I'm not really following what the issue is, or why the two examples would act differently. Could you show the relevant plugin code?

Comment: What plugin are you using?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry I've forgot to insert the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/CFPTa/

Comment: in the jsfiddle example you can see the first child of the table second column is treated as the first-chid of the first column, does exist some way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).bind('mousemove', {i:instances[$(this).index()]}, setFollowMouse);
```

Should be

```
$(this).bind('mousemove', {i:instances[i]}, setFollowMouse);
```

Using `.index()` was giving you the index of the element within its parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/CFPTa/17/